# Got this error while installing NODE JS

Tags: node.js, linux, linux-mint

I am trying to install by this

```
sudo npm install
```

Got this error

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/mean/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.8.0-53-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/opt/mean/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /opt/mean/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v9.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@6.0.2 requires a peer of eslint@^2.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@6.0.2 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ranjit/.npm/_logs/2018-01-12T07_23_24_314Z-debug.lo
```

g

I have chnaged the permission also. But did not work for me.

Source - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-mean-js-stack-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

Comment: Try to login as root user first `sudo -i`.

Comment: Please answer it So that i can accept it. You save my time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to login as root user first with this command `sudo -i`.